# mod_rewrite how to preserve query string?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been looking all over the internet but I just can't find a solution.

I've been trying to pass a query string as another $_GET value in php.
For example `localhost/find/book` translates to `index.php?url=find/book` but that's not enough for my purpose. When I try to do something like `localhost/find/book?cols=name,library` I want this to translate to `index.php?url=find/book?cols=name,library` but instead it translates to `index.php?url=find/book` it just omits the second query string.

I'm pretty sure that I did this a couple of months ago and it worked. But now it just doesn't and I don't know why.

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead, you could also use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]` and get the URL via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your index.php. No need for a url param then.

Comment: @jeroen 's approach was exactly what I was looking for. Your answer gives the raw URI. In my case I don't need the extra question mark, I was going to explode the last part of the QS on the question mark anyway and then again another explode on the commas. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QSA` option that you are already using does just that.

However, there is no such thing as a second query string, so you url will not translate to:

```
index.php?url=find/book?cols=name,library
```

but instead to something like:

```
index.php?url=find/book&cols=name,library
                       ^ here
```

Note that you have to take care that you output valid query strings (using for example `urlencode` in php) as otherwise your application might not behave as you think it should. Your comma for example should be encode as `%2C` but you should let `urlencode` take care of that.

Comment: I guess I was looking in the wrong direction. Thanks @jeroen!

Comment: Right, the possibility of invalid strings is a good point. I guess I wouldn't have thought about it until I'd run into a problem with that :)